# Calculate Entropy from pressure and energy

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, pressure, entropy

It's given that for a particular special gas, the pressure and the energy is given by,

$
\begin{aligned}
P &=\left(\sqrt{\frac{N}{V}}\right) \frac{T^{2}}{A} \\
E &=2 \sqrt{N V} \frac{T^{2}}{A}
\end{aligned} $

Where $N$ is the particle number and $A$ is a constant. Using entropy $ S = -\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}$, and pressure $ P = -\frac{\partial F}{\partial V} $; where $F$ is the free energy, how can we get an expression for the entropy as a function of $V, N,$ and $T$?

Answer (score 2):

Use the chain rule,

$\frac{\partial F }{\partial T } = \frac{\partial V }{\partial T} \frac{\partial F }{\partial V}$

This gives you

$S = \frac{\partial V }{\partial T} P $

Comment: Thanks! Now, using your method, I found $ S = \frac{4T \sqrt{NV} }{A}$. But assuming I expand the gas isothermally from $V_1$ to $V_2$, the change in entropy seems to differ from the earlier expression by a factor of 2. What might cause this?

Comment: Your welcome, what do you mean by "earlier expression" ?

Answer (score 0):

The Helmoltz free energy is the Legendre transform of the internal energy
$F(T,V,N) = E- T S$. Its differential reads: $dF = -S dT -p dV + \mu dN$, or in other words: $\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial T} \right)_{V,N} = - S$,$\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial V} \right)_{T,N} = - p$,$\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial N} \right)_{T,V} = \mu$.

We know the pressure $p$ so we can integrate it to find:
\begin{equation}F(T,V,N) = \int_{V_0}^V \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial V} \right)_{T,N} dV + N \tilde h(T) =
\int_{V_0}^V (-p) dV+ N \tilde h(T) = -2 \sqrt{VN}\frac{T^2}{A} + N h(T). \end{equation}
$\tilde h(T)$ and $h(T)$ differ by a constant contribution of the lower integration bound. $N$ factor was extracted from $h$ to make it an intensive quantity.

Now we can find entropy as: \begin{equation} S= -\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial T} \right)_{V,N} = 4 \sqrt{VN}\frac{T^2}{A} - N h'(T)\end{equation}.
We still have to figure out the $h$ function. For that, we turn back to the definition: $F=E-TS$. We find:
\begin{equation}
-2 \sqrt{VN}\frac{T^2}{A} + N h(T) = 2 \sqrt{VN}\frac{T^2}{A} - 4 \sqrt{VN}\frac{T^2}{A} + N T h'(T),\\
 h(T) = T h'(T)\; \implies\; h(T) = -T s_0, \; h'(T) = -s_0
\end{equation}
where $s_0$ is some constant.

We finally conclude $S(T,V,N) = 4\sqrt{VN} \frac{T^2}{A} + N s_0$, with $s_0$ remaining an underdetermined constant.

Note: I cannot comment on other solutions yet. I don't understand the Klan Maleki's solution. I think that his use of the chain rule is incorrect. It is hard to judge, though, because he writes derivatives without specifying the independent variables.
Also, how do you find $\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}$ in this problem? Shouldn't $T$ and $V$ be independent variables?